# How do I fix my nav menu?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am working on a site and after I loaded light box on the gallery page, Nivo slider on the home page and html 5 Lightbox for video on the about me page the nav menu doesn't show up on Android stock browser or chrome from android. It works fine on iPhones that I have tested. Here is the link   -

http://www.madisonderousse.com/MED/MED/index.html.

It works fine on all browsers on a PC.

Answer (score 1):

you need change this line :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

to be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```